# Integrating an exponential with a power of a sine function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I need some urgent help! I want to compute this integral

$$
\int e^{\left(\mu + r\right)t + \frac{r}{\alpha}\text{sin}\left(\alpha t\right)} dt
$$

can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: Have you tried Wolfram alpha?

Comment: Unfortunately it can't be integrated indefinitely. Any tips?

Comment: Symbolic integration is indeed not possible. What exactly do you need ?

Comment: I needed an analytic solution to implement within a block of code, it is part of a wider problem of finding the solution to $dN/dt = (1+cos(\alpha t)) * r(c-N)-\mu N$